Why I am getting Cascade delete cycle error when updating the database
I am getting delete cascade error like below:

Error Number:1785,State:0,Class:16
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Products_Categories_CategoriesId' on table 'Products' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I have check other solutions of related problem but nothing seems to working here.
this is my Product class
public class Products : ITimeAuditable
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Range(0, double.MaxValue)] 
    public double StockAmount { get; set; }

    [Range(0, double.MaxValue)] 
    public double MinStockAmount { get; set; }

    [Range(0, double.MaxValue)] 
    public double UnitPrice { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)] 
    public string UnitType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedAtUtc { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdatedAtUtc { get; set; }
    public string? UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public Users User { get; set; }

    public int? CategoriesId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoriesId")]
    public Categories Categories { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Transactions> Transactions { get; set; } = new List<Transactions>();

}

this is my dbcontext
    builder.Entity<Products>()
.HasOne(p => p.User)
.WithMany(u => u.Products)
.HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction); 

    builder.Entity<Products>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Categories)
        .WithMany(c => c.Products)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoriesId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); 
}

Transactions entity
public class Transactions
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Range(0, double.MaxValue)] 
    public double Qty { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string? UnitType { get; set; }

    [Range(0, double.MaxValue)] 
    public double TotalPrice { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)] 
    public string? TransactionTypes { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public Users Users { get; set; }

    public string? ProductsId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductsId")]
    public Products? Products { get; set; }
}

Users entity
public class Users : IdentityUser, ITimeAuditable
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedAtUtc { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdatedAtUtc { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Products> Products { get; set; } = new List<Products>();
    public ICollection<Transactions> Transactions { get; set; } = new List<Transactions>();
}

public class Categories:ITimeAuditable
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAtUtc { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAtUtc { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Products> Products { get; set; }

    public string UsersId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UsersId")]
    public Users Users { get; set; }
}

I checked by putting both Restrict but same result.

There are more relations involved - Products are references by Transactions, so maybe the problem lies somewhere there?

I added.plz check

The exception tell you what's going on and what to do about it. Did you really try to understand what it says? The key thing is: you have to do something about it. We can't help you ignore it or work around it. It's impossible.

actually, I tried all these things. didn't work for me. There is now one option left, changing the relationship.

And that's exactly what I said. Please look at the numerous question on this exception. They appear all the time, mostly because people don't simply do what the message says.

After checking the repo and I am facing the same issue, here is the output. Then we can copy the sql statement and excute it in the database, then we can find more details.
PM> Update-Database -Context AppDbContext
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Applying migration '20240925073600_init'.
Failed executing DbCommand (8ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [Products] (
    [Id] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    [StockAmount] float NOT NULL,
    [MinStockAmount] float NOT NULL,
    [UnitPrice] float NOT NULL,
    [UnitType] nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAtUtc] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedAtUtc] datetime2 NULL,
    [UserId] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    [CategoriesId] int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Products] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Products_AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Products_Categories_CategoriesId] FOREIGN KEY ([CategoriesId]) REFERENCES [Categories] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Products_Categories_CategoriesId' on table 'Products' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:e7a38f43-b64e-4c75-a5d7-dea3e0c6042c
Error Number:1785,State:0,Class:16
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Products_Categories_CategoriesId' on table 'Products' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.


Reason
Form the error message, we find the Products entity is related to the Users and Categories entities through the UserId and CategoriesId foreign keys, and Transactions is related to Products and Users. When trying to delete one of the entities, EF Core may encounter multiple cascading delete paths, resulting in conflicts.
So you can try to fix by using below settings.
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<Products>()
        .HasOne(p => p.User)
        .WithMany(u => u.Products)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    builder.Entity<Transactions>()
        .HasOne(t => t.Users)
        .WithMany(u => u.Transactions)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.UserId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    builder.Entity<Transactions>()
        .HasOne(t => t.Products)
        .WithMany(p => p.Transactions)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.ProductsId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    builder.Entity<Products>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Categories)
        .WithMany(c => c.Products)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoriesId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    builder.Entity<Categories>()
        .HasOne(c => c.Users)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.UsersId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}

Also, remove the [ForeignKey] data annotations from the Products entity as we define it in the db context.
Updated Products Entity
public class Products : ITimeAuditable
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Range(0, double.MaxValue)] 
    public double StockAmount { get; set; }

    [Range(0, double.MaxValue)] 
    public double MinStockAmount { get; set; }

    [Range(0, double.MaxValue)] 
    public double UnitPrice { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)] 
    public string UnitType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedAtUtc { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdatedAtUtc { get; set; }
    public string? UserId { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public Users User { get; set; }

    public int? CategoriesId { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("CategoriesId")]
    public Categories Categories { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Transactions> Transactions { get; set; }

}

Then run the command to update the database.
add-migration test //[optional]-context  WebApplication5Context
update-database //[optional]-context  WebApplication5Context


problem not solved yet. same issues

Hi @SAFIQULISLAMUZZAL203-15-144 Could you create a brand new sample project( hide your sensitive information) which can reproduce the issue for you? If we can debug it, the issue will be fixed as soon as possible. Thanks

its actually a pet project, so i sharing the github link.
https://github.com/ishanuzzal/StockManagement

Hi @SAFIQULISLAMUZZAL203-15-144 Just now I am checking the issue, and I find below sql statement `CREATE TABLE [Products] (
[Id] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
[Name] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
[StockAmount] float NOT NULL,
[M....

@SAFIQULISLAMUZZAL203-15-144 Are you facing same error ? If yes, please try to check the table [AspNetUsers] and [Categories] exist or not in your localdb. And we also can try to run this sql statement in database manually, to check what error shows, thanks

i think it have problems because of mismatch of migration with database. I put them into a different database and things solved. thanks

Hi @SAFIQULISLAMUZZAL203-15-144 Does the suggestion useful to you ? I mean did you face the same sql statement when the issue occurs. If yes, I will summarize it and update my answer, thanks
